# C/C++: how to figure out link flags?

Tags: c++, c, linker

How do I reliably figure out link flags for libraries? I always end up googling/digging manuals.

Is there a way to list libraries available for linking, with names and/or descriptions?

edit: Linux system, GNU build chain, classics.

Comment: Read the library documentation ...

Comment: linking semantics vary across operating systems and compilers.  We'd need a lot more detail to make any useful contributions.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkg-config

Comment: Post that as an answer, @BoBTFish :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On most Linux systems, you can use [`pkg-config`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkg-config) to list out the compiler options for a given library. For example:

```
g++ example.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libpng)
```

becomes

```
g++ example.cpp -I/usr/include/libpng12 -lpng12
```

Or an example with slightly more complicated output:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs gthread
-D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/glib-1.2 -I/usr/lib64/glib/include  -lgthread -lpthread -lglib
```

Comment: Also worth noting: `locate --regex pkgconfig/.*pc$` will list available package data for `pkgconfig`.